# Microsoft Office Communicator (MOC) chat history?

Tags: history, chat, ms-office-communicator

**How can I access Microsoft Office Communicator chat history?**

It looks like the only built-in way to do this is to use Microsoft Exchange server -- is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There doesnt seem to be any way to save a log on the client other than manually saving each conversation.

Answer (score 3):

First of all do [enable saving message history](http://hosting.intermedia.net/support/kb/default.asp?id=1406):

> Tools -> Options -> check "Save my instant message conversations in
>   the Outlook History folder" -> after that logout from your "OC"
>   account and restart "OC"

After that you'll be able to see [conversation history](http://www.ehow.com/how_8314924_see-conversation-history-office-communicator.html):

> Tools - > View conversation history

Comment: This seems to assume Outlook (and Exchange?) integration.  There isn't a way to do this without integrating with Outlook?

Answer (score 2):

Pidgin with the libsipe.dll will log just fine, seems to work well enough (it didn't used to do group chat, but it seems to work now, though I've not used it much).

Pidgin can also do spellcheck, unlike MOC.

http://sipe.sourceforge.net/

MOC is amazingly bad, we have a number of workstations that it will not run on.

Answer (score 0):

The following steps should help you:

- Select <kbd>?</kbd>
- Select 'Save Instant Communication History in Outlook'
- Finally, in the new options window, put a tick near 'Save History'

Comment: This answer can be improved - especially this bit "or smth like that"